# Check failed: ReadProtoFromBinaryFile(param_file, param) Failed to parse NetParameter file

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, caffe, pycaffe

I want to use a caffemodel trained by someone else to test my own data but meet this error:`Check failed: ReadProtoFromBinaryFile(param_file, param) Failed to parse NetParameter file`
I've checked the deploy.prototxt and train&test path,they are all correct.

what reason may lead to this error,please?

someone says that the caffemodel might not complete.how can I make sure it is complete or not?

Comment: Usually when this message is printed, it shows the line number + column number of the prototxt, and a reason (e.g. expected identifier). You should check that specific line.

Comment: it is still there, no info to help troubleshooting, tried ver 3.4 & 4.2:
Emgu.CV.Util.CvException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=OpenCV: FAILED: ReadProtoFromTextFile(param_file, param). Failed to parse NetParameter file: bvlc_googlenet.prototxt
  Source=Emgu.CV.World.NetStandard
  StackTrace:
   at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.CvErrorHandler(Int32 status, IntPtr funcName, IntPtr errMsg, IntPtr fileName, Int32 line, IntPtr userData)
   at Emgu.CV.Dnn.DnnInvoke.cveReadNetFromCaffe(IntPtr prototxt, IntPtr caffeModel)
   at Emgu.CV.Dnn.DnnInvoke.ReadNetFromCaffe(String prototxt, String caffeModel)